# IIF Condition Ques

Tags: t-sql, business-intelligence

Can someone explain this condition, because I'm getting wrong Time data eg : I'm expecting sch departure time as 15.10 but I'm getting 15.01

```
[Sch Dep Time] = IIF(DATEPART(Hour,[Journey and Details.schdeptime]) < 10 AND DATEPART(Minute,[Journey and Details.schdeptime]) < 10,
                 ('0' + DATEPART(Hour,[Journey and Details.schdeptime]) + ':0' + DATEPART(Minute,[Journey and Details.schdeptime])),
                     IIF(DATEPART(Hour,[Journey and Details.schdeptime]) < 10,
                         ('0' + DATEPART(Hour,[Journey and Details.schdeptime]) + ':' + DATEPART(Minute,[Journey and Details.schdeptime])),
                         (DATEPART(Hour,[Journey and Details.schdeptime]) + ':0' + DATEPART(Minute,[Journey and Details.schdeptime]))))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: What is the input and why do you think `15:10` is incorrect? The code appears to stuff leading zeros into a string so that both the hours and minutes have two digits. Aside: If you take the expression and play with it you ought to be able to see what is going on. Declare a variable with a test value (`declare @Sample as DateTime = '1999-12-31T01:02';`) and substitute it into a `select` for testing: `select @Sample, IIF(DATEPART(Hour,@Sample) < 10 AND ...;`. If it still isn't clear, select parts of the expression as columns, e.g. output the hour and minute or the result of one `IIF` separately.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

It suddenly hit me that `[Sch Dep Time]` should contain the time component of the `dataTime` value stored in `[Journey and Details.schdeptime]`, in a minute resolution. For that, you don't need to mess around with specific date parts and string concatenation, all you have to do is use [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles):

```
[Sch Dep Time] = CONVERT(char(5), [Journey and Details.schdeptime], 108)
```

The 108 style returns `hh:mm:ss` (24 hours), and by using `char(5)` you are just taking the first 5 chars of that string - `hh:mm`.

### First version

You have overcomplicated things. Try using the old `right('00' + val, 2)` trick instead:

```
[Sch Dep Time] = RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(Hour,[Journey and Details.schdeptime]) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
                 RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(Minute,[Journey and Details.schdeptime]) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

Exlpanation:

You start off by concatenating leading zeroes to the string you want.
Suppose you have a string representing a number that must always have 4 digits, but it might be 1234 or 0003 - so you start by doing `'0000' + @YourNumber`.
Then, you use `RIGHT` to trim off any unwanted zeros - suppose you now have `000023`, but you want `0023` - you do `RIGHT('000023', 4)` to get the last 4 chars.

Comment: Can you explain a bit ,what exactly are we doing here?

Comment: @AseemSharma I've added an explanation

Comment: Thank you so much,your help is appreciated.

Comment: ,can you correct the above logic as i cannot use cast in my script then i need to change lot of things..i just want that for minutes when its less then 10 it should add 0 infront of it but after it

Comment: my logic is adding 0 before number whenever something is ending with 0

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. You have to cast to `varchar` (or `nvarchar`) to concatenate the strings, otherwise SQL Server will implicitly convert the strings to ints.

Comment: I'm sorry, Your initial over-complication got me over-complicating things myself. See my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry, missed the `C` at the begging of `convert`. Fixed.